# Batch Script Deleting Files Instead of Moving

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I am still a beginner to batch scripting so I would appreciate more explanation than usual to help me if at all possible.

**Purpose:**

I wrote this script to try to move files based on whether they have a folder's name within their name. For example, I have a folder named "cow" and a file named "cow_5234.txt", the file would be moved into the folder. The purpose of this is to move files with company names to a company folder from a messy folder full of files so I don't think a file going to the wrong folder will be much of a problem.

**Problem:**

The problem I am having is that many of the files that are supposed to be transferred to folders are being misplaced. I have around 3000 files in a folder along with 300 folders and this script. After I run it, only around 100 files get placed into the correct folders, while 900 are left behind (because they don't have a folder name within them) while the rest just disappear.

**What I have tried to do:**

I have gone through and checked the original list of folder names, which is all correct. Then I modified the script to output the filename to a .txt file instead of move it. Instead of getting a reasonable amount of files, there are 4000 files (I checked the line count). Some of these files don't have a folder name in them. I then took a subset of around 200 files and 20 folders and ran the script with them. For some reason, only 80 files remained, 1 was placed into a folder, although it didn't have a single similar character as the folder, and the rest just disappeared. I'm not sure what is happening at all. Here is the code:

```
    @echo off
    dir /a:d /b > list.txt
    for /F %%i in (list.txt) do call :process %%i
    goto :eof

    :process
    set "search=%1"
    for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /A:-D /b^|find "%search%"') do move /Y "%%F" "%search%"
    goto :eof
```

**Edit 1:**

As recommended in the comments, I have added a "goto :eof" to the end of the block of code, however, the problem still remains.

**Edit 2:**

I didn't add a "goto :eof" to the end of the main function. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: You need a `goto :eof` after the main block of code. As your function is executed one extra time as your code goes to the end of the file. `%1` and thus `%search%` will be blank. It is good practise to end functions with a `goto :eof`. If you have more than one function you have to.

Comment: Samraj, there should also be a `goto` at the end of the *main* code block, just after the `for` statement. *That's* what CatCat was suggesting, I believe.